# Retain millisecond description in timestamp in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a string `'2023-04-12 14:29:15.352000'` that I wish to convert into a timestampTZ datatype column in Redshift. I read through [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html) documentation and I am seeing a strange behavior.

When I do

```
select to_timestamp('2023-04-12 14:29:15.352000', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:MI:SS')
```

I get all the expected conversions except for milliseconds. But when I add `MS` to my format string like this

```
select to_timestamp('2023-04-12 14:29:15.352000', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:MI:SS.MS')
```

I get a totally incorrect conversion whose output is `2023-04-12 14:35:07.000000 +00:00`. Notice the incorrect minute and seconds. Is there a bug with this Redshift function or what am I missing?

Comment: ok, i just realized the issue with the milliseconds is due to it having 6digits and `MS` only covers 3 digits. But for my case, is it possible to cover all 6 digits?

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to just do

```
select cast('2023-04-12 14:29:15.352000' as timestamptz)
```